# How to search/replace text being copied before sending to clipboard using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, copy-paste

I managed to add text to what's being copied using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777746/686617)(the second option). However, when I change the string concatenation and add a call to `replace`, I get an error "replace is not a function".

```
copytext = window.getSelection().replace(/some pattern/, 'replace value'); // Fails
```

The "selection" object seems to be very complex and I can't even find the text inside it. I could call `toString` on it but that's not an option because I'm copying HTML from a contenteditable div and I need to preserve the formatting.

I'm trying to do this because I have relative links in the div's content and they're being converted to absolute links in the copied text for some reason. This only happens when accessing [my demo](https://rawgit.com/arielpontes/footnoter/master/index.html) from rawgit. Locally, it works normally.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Here's a jsfiddle with my current setup: https://jsfiddle.net/8kx8v8pb/

Comment: The `+` operator just coerces the object to a string. Call `.toString()` explicitly (or fake it with `+ ""`)

Comment: `the second option` - so you're only interested in IE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176923/html-of-selected-text/4177234#4177234 show how to get the html out of the selection object.

Comment: @JaromandaX , not really, it just seemed shorter and according to @mems ' comment it works on other browsers as well if you replace `window.clipboardData` with `event.clipboardData`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to a string (`getSelection()` returns a Selection object).
So either append a "" or cast it to a string with `.toString()` before executing the `.replace()`

so in your case, the code should be like this:

```
copytext = (window.getSelection() + "").replace(/some pattern/, 'replace value');
```

or

```
copytext = (window.getSelection().toString()).replace(/some pattern/, 'replace value');
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Comment: The problem with this is that I loose all the formatting in the content being copied. To be more explicit, I have a contenteditable div with rich text inside of it, including links etc. If I use `toString` I loose all of that.

Answer (score 0):

selection is a object so if you want to run the replace function on its text then use following.

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.data.replace(/some pattern/, 'replace value');
```

I hope this will help

Comment: This does work but only for the first element in my selection. My selection has multiple nodes, I suppose I could loop through them and apply `replace` to each? Like I said I'm not familiar with the structure of javascript selections so I'm having a hard time trying to do even something as simple as looping though the nodes, so assistance is appreciated.

Comment: can you post your complete code here?. it would be great if you can create jsfiddle for this.