# How can i get formatted HTML of selected part instead of simple text through this JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can i get formatted HTML of selected part instead of simple text

Here is a script that add content to `<div class="container"> </div>`  when we select some text and press  <kbd>Get Selection</kbd> button, with every time class `mySlides` Okay

But here is all text goes in one by one only in this structure, even though we select any HTML text like `<p> <h2>` etc part.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mySlides"> Some Text </div>
<div class="mySlides"> Some other </div>
<div class="mySlides"> Some another </div>
</div>
```

But Now i want a little change here, my requirement is When i select text then it should be get with formatted rendered HTML Just Like This.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mySlides"> Some Text </div>

<div class="mySlides"> 
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
     <p>
          Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button
   </p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides"> Some another </div>
</div>
```

i also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176923/html-of-selected-text) but i am not able to get solve my issue.
means simple i want rendered HTML format of selection.

**My Whole Code IS Here:**

```js
const keySelected = new Set();

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    keySelected.add(e.which);
    if(keySelected.has(17) && keySelected.has(90)){
        getSelectedText();
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
     keySelected.delete(e.which);
});


// Function to get the Selected Text  
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  // #### create a new element with variable (nw) #### //
  var nw = document.createElement("div"); // Element's tag
  nw.className = "mySlides"; // Element's class name
   // some applied style

  // window.getSelection 
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  }
  // document.getSelection 
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  }
  // document.selection 
  else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText =
      document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  // #### get the Selected text appended to body #### //
  nw.innerHTML = selectedText;
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].prepend(nw); // Append element to body
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container"> </div>

<button id="mybtn" onclick="getSelectedText()">Get Selection</button>

  <p>
          Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button
   </p> 
   <h3>This is heading 3</h3>
     <p>
          Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button
   </p>
```

Plz Help Me How to do that.

Comment: do you mean that it should be selected with its kind of tags

Comment: not HTML Tags, i want Rendered HTML Like Not to be with <b> </> but it should be as Strong or Bold

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b75cqzoy/) ?

Comment: Yes Swati Thanks a Lot