# Get selected text with highlighted text with tag in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

`my <span class="highlight">highlighted</span> word`

In above selected text include html tag. When I use `window.getSelection()` returns only the text without tag `my highlighted word` but I need entire selected text with `<span>` tag as above. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176923/html-of-selected-text/4177234#4177234

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the inner HTML of a given tag you shoul try to use innerHTML prop.
EG:

For a tag:

```
<p id="high">My <span class="highlight">Highlighted</span></p>
```

You can store the node in a variable like:

```
const text = document.getElementById("high");
```

And if you access the prop innerHTML it will return you the value inside the p tag

```
console.log(text.innerHTML)
```

Result: "My <span class="highlight">Highlighted"

Answer (score 0):

Can try something like this

```
   window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by using

`window.getSelection().getRangeAt (0).cloneContents ()`