# How to edit a formatted text in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use replace on a formatted text and to place the result in the clipboard. But `.replace()` works only with string. I have to replace hyperlinked links in clipboard. I'm trying to learn javascript but it's hard.

```
var text = window.getSelection();
var modified=text.replace("https://google", "google");
e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', modified);
```

I checked `.setData` ad it allows only text not formatted string.

Comment: Try `"text/html"` format.

Comment: It works thanks, but I don't get the replace to work.

Comment: `window.getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object, not a string. Calling `.replace` on it converts it to a simple string first, composed of the `textContent` of selected nodes, not their `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`. Have a look at how the `Selection` object works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection It seems possible to extract the selected elements from it along with their HTML content, if you'd like to replace parts of the HTML before copying it to the clipboard.

Comment: Here is how to get the selected HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177234/600135