# How to take print selected content from div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, html, printing

I have some content in div area. I want to take printout the selected content from div.
In my javsscript,

For example, If i select **3 lines** from div content, **after print out**, i get the 3 line content as **single line**. not **3** line.

My code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>

<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">


            function printPartialContent(divContentId)
            {
                var selectedContent = "";
                selectedContent= document.getSelection();

                var textPopupWindow = window.open('','popup','toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1,height=1 left=-5000');
                textPopupWindow.document.open();
                textPopupWindow.document.write(makeTextPrint(selectedContent));
                textPopupWindow.document.close();
            }

            function makeTextPrint(textContent)
            {
                // We break the closing script tag in half to prevent
                // the HTML parser from seeing it as a part of
                // the *main* page.

                return  "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "<script>\n" +
                    "function step1() {\n" +
                    "  setTimeout('step2()', 10);\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "function step2() {\n" +
                    "  window.print();\n" +
                    "  window.close();\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "</scr" + "ipt>\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "<body onLoad='step1()'>\n" +
                    textContent +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>\n";
            }

        </script>
    </head>
 <body>
        <h:form id="parameterform">

            <rich:panel id="divPanelPanel">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Div Content Demo"/>
                </f:facet>

                <a4j:outputPanel id="divOutputPanel">


                    <div id="contentDivId" style="text-align:left">

                        ******* Details 1 *******<br>
                        28/02/2011 08.19.00<br>
                        5641620100333718 566<br>
                        Value: 2000<br>
                        Counter : 123<br>  
                        ******* Details 2 *******<br>
                        16/10/2000 9.10.00<br>
                        56345345333718<br>
                        Value: 3000<br>
                        Counter : 765<br>                          
                    </div>

<a4j:commandButton value="Partial Content" 
onclick="printPartialContent('contentDivId')"/>


                 </a4j:outputPanel>

            </rich:panel>
</h:form
</body> </html></f:view>
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getSelection() returns selected text as plain text not HTML so any formatting you have will be lost when you output the selection to your print window/div.
To copy text as HTML check out [HTML of selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176923/html-of-selected-text) or [Getting selected text in a browser, cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478/getting-selected-text-in-a-browser-cross-platform)

Comment: Actually in most current browsers `document.getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object rather than a string, but calling `toString()` on that Selection does give you the plain text of the selection as you say.