# Getting HTML Selection

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

I am using the code above that's provided here: [How to get selected html text with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript).

However, there are so inconsistencies with the actual html and the html that's returned by the function. For example, given the following html:

```
<div>
<p><b>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy <a href="www.google.com">dog</a></b></p>
<img src="http://www.fakingnews.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/kim-jaya.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<hr>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy <a href="http://www.google.com">dog</a></p>
<li>
    <ul>1</ul>
    <ul>2</ul>
    <ul>3</ul>
    <ul>4</ul>
    <ul>5</ul>
</li>
</div>
<br />
<input id="showSelected" type="button" value="showSelected" />
```

If I was to select

```
x jumps over the lazy <a href="http://www.google.com">dog</a></p>
<li>
    <ul>1</ul>
    <ul>2</ul>
    <ul>3</ul>
```

The function actually returns

```
<div><p>x jumps over the lazy <a href="http://www.google.com">dog</a></p>
<li>
    <ul>1</ul>
    <ul>2</ul>
    <ul>3</ul>
    <ul>4</ul>
    <ul>5</ul>
</li>
</div>
```

I've noticed that the extra tags in the front appear when I also select a list, but I'm sure there are other instances of inconsistency as well. Is there anything I can do to get an exact HTML copy?

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are selecting is not a valid HTML, for example has missing opening and closing tags, so the code you listed in your question wont work as expected,
In your case you need to use a Text Selection function, something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/169873/200713

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var txt = '';

  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  else return; 

  return txt;
}
```